# pandas new column with difference from series object list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, numpy

I have a list lets say:

```
x_lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

and a df like:

```
col_A, col_B
3      [4,3,2]
9      [1,2,3,4,5]
1      [5]
2      [3]
```

with data types:

```
col_A            int
col_B            object
dtype: object
```

now  i am trying to create a new column col_C that writes the difference between x_lst and the col_B

expected res:

```
col_A, col_B         col_C
3      [4,3,2]       False
9      [1,2,3,4,5]   [6,7,8,9]
1      [5]           False
2      [3]           [1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

for this i have tried something:

```
df['col_C'] = np.where(df.col_A != df.col_B.str.len(), x_lst - df.col_B, 'FALSE')
```

but this gave error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (9,) (7964,)
```

and if i use tolist():

```
df['col_C'] = np.where(df.col_A != df.col_B.str.len(), x_lst - df.col_B.tolist(), 'FALSE')
```

i get:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'
```

Comment: Why does the expected value of col_c include false two times?

Comment: becase the value of `col_A ==  len(col_B)`

Comment: ^ in thos particular rows the condition matches, hence `False` value is there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using `set`:

`df.col_B.map(set(x_lst).difference).map(list)` instead of `x_lst - df.col_B`

```
import numpy as np
df['col_C'] = np.where(df.col_A != df.col_B.str.len(), df.col_B.map(set(x_lst).difference).map(list), 'FALSE')
```

---

**df:**

```
  col_A col_B               col_C
0   3   [4, 3, 2]           FALSE
1   9   [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]     [6, 7, 8, 9]
2   1   [5]                 FALSE
3   2   [3]                 [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: is it possible to map the list in col_C with a dict? like dd = {1: "dum1", 2: "dum2" } and have the list in col_D like ["dum1", "dum2"]?

Comment: @YawnLun Yes It is.

Comment: please look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65954374/pandas-mapping-list-to-dict-items-for-new-column